# Detecting if user has readonly or comment only permission for a Google Document

Tags: google-drive-api

If a user has readonly or comment only access to a document, is there a way to check which of these permission does the user has using that user's credentials?

I tried https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list api using credentials of a user who has read access to a document, and then crendentials for a user who has comment only permissions and the reponse from the server was identical. Both times, the response only had an entry for the owner and no other entries. There was no other data either to indicate what type of access does the user who made the request has.

I have also tried https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get api. This api has a flag editable which is false when the user doesn't have write access. However, it doesn't seem to have any info to figure out if user has comment access or read access.

Answer (score 1):

The [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource) resource returned by the permissions api will have "commenter" as an "additionalRoles" for that user.